# c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c++, arrays, char

i have a problem on this code
the errors says ISO c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

here is the exercise problem
-the answers to a true false test are as follows TTFFT given a two dimensional answer array in which each row corresponds to the answers provided on one test, write a function that accepts the two dimensional array and the number of tests as parameters and returns a one dimensional array containing the grades for each test.(each question is worth 5 points so that the maxinum possible grade is 25)

any answers will help.

this is the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int numberofgrades(char [][5], int []);

int main()
{
char testanswers[5][5] = {0};
int testgrades[5] = {0};
int counting1, counting2, counting3;

counting1 = 1;
counting2 = 1;
counting3 = 1;

cout << "this program will record the testgrades you entered: "
     << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        cout << "enter answers for test no. " << counting1  << ": ";
        cin >> testanswers[i][k];
    }
    counting1++;
}

numberofgrades(testanswers,testgrades);



cout << "testing..." << endl;
cout << endl;

for(int o = 0; o < 5; o++)
{
    cout << "test no. " << counting2;
    for(int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
    {
        cout << " " << testanswers[o][l];
    }
    counting2++;
    cout << endl;
}

cout << "testing...." << endl;

cout << endl;

cout << "the total number of scores per test no. is: "
     << endl;

for(int t = 0; t < 5; t++)
{
    cout << "test no. " << t << ": " << testgrades[t] << endl;
}

return 0;
}

int numberofgrades(char t1a [][5], int tg1[])
{
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(t1a[i] == 't') //this is the problem
        {
        tg1[j] = tg1[j] + 5;
        }
        else if(t1a[i] == 'T')
        {
        tg1[j] = tg1[j] + 5;
        }
        else if(t1a[i] == 'f')
        {
        tg1[j] = tg1[j] + 0;
        }
        else if(t1a[i] == 'F')
        {
        tg1[j] = tg1[j] + 0;
        }
        else{
            cout << "invalid letter exiting the program"
                 << endl;
                 return 0;
        }
    }
    }

 return tg1[5];
}
```

Comment: `t1a` is a 2D array. It must be accessed using 2 indexes like `t1a[i][j]`

Comment: or `t[j][i]` in this case

Comment: ohh thank you it works i forgot to put

Comment: I'm voting to close this, as it appears that the question is no longer relevant.